# Django app custom clean up for code reload

Tags: django

my Django project has an app which overrides its `AppConfig.ready()` method. In the ready method, I'm starting a separate `multiprocessing.Process` to handle consuming from an external message queue, this seems to be causing problems with autoreload on code changes.

```
def infinite_loop():
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)


class BrokerConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'backend.broker'
    has_started = False

    def ready(self):
        if not os.environ.get("RUN_MAIN"):
            # Avoid running for reloader
            return

        if BrokerConfig.has_started:
            return
        BrokerConfig.has_started = True

        proc = Process(target=infinite_loop)
        proc.start()
```

For whatever reason, this causes the automatic code reload to break. Seems the reloader is not able to clean up started processes. The reloader prints this and then gets stuck:

```
.../backend/broker/apps.py changed, reloading.
```

A way around this is to make the started process a daemon, but in case such a setting is not possible, I'm still curious how you might be able to get around this.

I am looking for some way to add some custom clean up when the reloading is happening, but I can't seem to find a way to do that. Is there some hook or signal you can subscribe to in order to find out if reloading has been triggered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it the other way around, so rather than listening or hooking into some Django signal to indicate "code reload incoming", I added a listener in my started process for SIGTERM. When reload occurs, the code reload will lead to daemon processes being terminated and thus receiving a SIGTERM signal. I did not find a way to do this with non-daemon processes.

### End solution

```
def infinite_loop():
    stop = False

    def stop():
        nonlocal stop
        stop = True

    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, stop)

    while True:
        if stop:
           break
        time.sleep(10)

class BrokerConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'backend.broker'
    has_started = False

    def ready(self):
        if not os.environ.get("RUN_MAIN"):
            # Avoid running for reloader
            return

        if BrokerConfig.has_started:
            return
        BrokerConfig.has_started = True

        proc = Process(target=infinite_loop, daemon=True)
        proc.start()
```

So, in the end I went for a daemon after all, and the cleanup I wanted was put into the scope of the started process (as a SIGTERM handler).